# How to instantly reverse flexbox item order with non-full row at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container in which I have around 128 items(the amount can change). I'll use 14 here. They go like this:

```
-----------------
|  1  2   3   4 |
|  5  6   7   8 |
|  9 10  11  12 |
| 13 14         |
-----------------
```

what im trying to achieve is reversing the order so that if the number of items is not divisible by 4 the items are always aligned to the left and the half-empty row is always at the bottom and the items arent stretched in any way. Like this:

```
-----------------
| 14 13  12  11 |
| 10  9   8   7 |
|  6  5   4   3 |
|  2  1         |
-----------------
```

I tried doing `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` and `flex-direction: row-reverse;` but that leaves me with a half-empty row at the top.

```
-----------------
| 14 13         |
| 12 11  10   9 |
|  8  7   6   5 |
|  4  3   2   1 |
-----------------
```

After not finding any solution to this I resorted to javascript where I tried changing the order properly.

```
let itemsCount = $('.flex-container').children().length;

for (let item of $('.flex-container').children()) {
   item.style.order = itemsCount;
   itemsCount--;
}
```

Which indeed worked! Well, kinda.. Because when I press the reverse button, I can actually see how the items each move during the for loop and it looks very ugly. I need it to be instant.

This is probably a beginner mistake so I really didn't want to ask here but after hours of unsuccessful attempts I gave up. Any feedback is very much appreciated.

**Demo:**

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.item {
  width: 330px;
  max-width: 330px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
  <div class="item item-3"></div>
  <div class="item item-4"></div>
  <div class="item item-5"></div>
  <div class="item item-6"></div>
  <div class="item item-7"></div>
  <div class="item item-8"></div>
  <div class="item item-9"></div>
  <div class="item item-10"></div>
  <div class="item item-11"></div>
  <div class="item item-12"></div>
  <div class="item item-13"></div>
  <div class="item item-14"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `order` property of CSS.

[More about `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

I could not find an easy way to make it work without Javascript, but at least it does the job by manipulating `style` only.

It does work no matter the amount of items is 14 or 128, and fit with any `width` of the container.

Hope this will help!

Example:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
const btnReverse = document.querySelector(".btn.reverse");
const btnNormal = document.querySelector(".btn.normal");

btnReverse.addEventListener("click", () => items.forEach((item, index, arr)=>item.style.order = arr.length - index))
btnNormal.addEventListener("click", () => items.forEach((item)=>item.style.order = ""))
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 220px;
  gap: 6px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.item {
  order: revert;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: large;
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
}

.btn {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn reverse">REVERSE</button>
<button class="btn normal">NORMAL</button>

<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
  <div class="item item-10">10</div>
  <div class="item item-11">11</div>
  <div class="item item-12">12</div>
  <div class="item item-13">13</div>
  <div class="item item-14">14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item {
    flex: 1 1 24%;
    
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid tomato;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
        <div class="item item-1">1</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2</div>
        <div class="item item-3">3</div>
        <div class="item item-4">4</div>
        <div class="item item-5">5</div>
        <div class="item item-6">6</div>
        <div class="item item-7">7</div>
        <div class="item item-8">8</div>
        <div class="item item-9">9</div>
        <div class="item item-10">10</div>
        <div class="item item-11">11</div>
        <div class="item item-12">12</div>
        <div class="item item-13">13</div>
        <div class="item item-14">14</div>
      </div>
```